# Dagger not injecting activity

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, mockk

I am currently working my way through this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-inject-mock-dependencies-into-android-components-using-dagger-androidinjector-e274c8f6a9a6), trying to mock dagger dependencies in android with Kotlin but am having some trouble.

I am receiving an error saying activityInjector is not initialised.

What am I doing wrong?

TestAppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        TestAppModule::class,
        ActivityModule::class,
        FragmentModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class
    ]
)
interface TestAppComponent : AndroidInjector<TestApp> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<TestApp>() {
        abstract fun appModule(appModule: TestAppModule): Builder
    }
}
```

TestApp

```
class TestApp: Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>  = activityInjector
}
```

Test Injector

```
class TestInjector(private val testAppModule: TestAppModule) {

    fun inject() {
        val testApp= ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() as TestApp

        DaggerTestAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(testAppModule)
            .create(testApp)
            .inject(testApp)
    }
}
```

Activity Module

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun provideNavigationActivity(): NavigationActivity
}
```

Instrumented Unit Test

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var navigationActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(NavigationActivity::class.java, true, true)

@MockK
private lateinit var repo: Repo

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)

    TestInjector(TestAppModule(repo)).inject()
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where `TestInjector` is used?

Comment: I've updated the original post, it is called in the setup function of my unit tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `ActivityTestRule` your activity is launched even before the `TestInjector` is called from your setup method. You need to defer activity launch until your `DaggerTestAppComponent` is built.

Try this:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var navigationActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(NavigationActivity::class.java, true, false) 
// ^^ Notice the third parameter here, passing false will not launch the activity

@MockK
private lateinit var repo: Repo

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    TestInjector(TestAppModule(repo)).inject()

    // Launch the activity now that TestInjector is called
    navigationActivityTestRule.launchActivity(Intent()) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dagger component at the onCreate of your app source

```
class TestApp: Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerTestAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>  = activityInjector
}
```

and componant change like this

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        TestAppModule::class,
        ActivityModule::class,
        FragmentModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class
    ]
)
interface TestAppComponent{

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        @BindsInstance fun application(app: TestApp): Builder
        fun build(): TestAppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: TestApp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this config is for mocking the app module during integration tests. The testinjector is called in the setup function of my tests. Shouldn't that replicate what your answer is describing?